# How to catch the return value of function that is scheduled using python schedule package

Tags: python, schedule

I have scheduled my function to run everyday at particular hour.

I am passing an argument to it and function returns a value which I need to use for further computation in my code.

How do I catch it?

code snippet:

```
import schedule as sd
import time

def dothis(h):
    h-=1
    print("Hour left : "+str(h))
    return(h)

h=24
d="14:00"
sd.every().day.at(d).do(dothis,h) # how to catch the value here?

while True:
    sd.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import schedule as sd
import time

def dothis(h):
    h-=1
    print("Hour left : "+str(h))
    return h

h=24
d="14:00"
sd.every().day.at(d).do(dothis,h)
a = dothis(h)
while True:
    sd.run_pending()
    return_value = a
    time.sleep(1)
```

simply assign the function to a variable and it will have reference to that object

[similar question here answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329502/where-does-a-python-schedule-scheduled-tasks-return-value-go)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import schedule as sd
import time
import pandas as pd

h = pd.Series(24)
h.to_csv('h.txt',header = None, index = None)

def dothis():
    with open('h.txt', 'r') as f:
        h = int(f.readline())
    print("Hour left : "+str(h))
    h -= 1
    new_h = pd.Series(h)
    new_h.to_csv('h.txt',header = None, index = None)

sd.every(1).seconds.do(dothis) 



while True:
    sd.run_pending()
    # you can always just call this to get your current value...
    # (even in another sheduled function, which is what i needed)
    """
    with open('h.txt', 'r') as f:
        h = int(f.readline())
    print(h)
    """    
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).