# Where does a Python `schedule` scheduled task's return value go?

Tags: python, schedule

I have a scheduled task that runs using the [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. Where does the return value of my task go? Does returning `True` have a different effect than returning `False`?

Example:

```
def foo():
    return False

schedule.every().day.do(foo)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't "go" anywhere. Every object has a reference count, and a call like

```
a = foo()
```

would simply increment the reference count of whatever object `False` refers to, to reflect that `a` is now *also* an reference to the same object.

In the absence of any such assignment, like with

```
foo()
```

the reference count simply is not incremented. If the only other reference to the value was a name local to `foo`, then the object would be subject to garbage collection.

Comment: So even though schedule calls it, it doesn't do anything with the return value? I should be returning `None` for readability?

Comment: You should just `return` without a value (if it's needed), to make it clear the value isn't used.

Comment: Okay, so the answer is that `do()` just executes `foo()` without assignment. Fantastic. Thank you.