# How can I access an object returned from a scheduled job?

Tags: python, return, schedule

I know similar questions have been asked before. In fact, I tried to use the following as a basis for what I am trying to do, which I found here: [How to catch the return value of function that is scheduled using python schedule package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365333/how-to-catch-the-return-value-of-function-that-is-scheduled-using-python-schedul).

```
import schedule as sd
import time

def dothis(h):
    h-=1
    print("Hour left : "+str(h))
    return h

h=24
d="14:00"
sd.every().day.at(d).do(dothis,h)
a = dothis(h)
while True:
    sd.run_pending()
    return_value = a
    time.sleep(1)
```

I tested the above code above after changing `sd.every().day.at(d).do(dothis,h)` to `sd.every(15).seconds.do(dothis, h)`, thinking that the value of h would decrease every time 'dothis' is invoked. The output is:

```
    Hour left : 23
    Hour left : 23
    Hour left : 23
    Hour left : 23
    Hour left : 23
```

I have been unable to find a way to return and access an object which will likely be different each time the scheduled job is run.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, every time `dothis` is called, it is passed the value `24` as an argument - python has no reference passing, so the parameter `h` in the function has no link to the global `h`.

One way to fix this is to use an object to hold the state, and call the bound method of the object. (In the below example, I modified it to run every second for ease of testing.)

```
import schedule as sd
import time


class State:
    def __init__(self):
        self.h = 24

    def dothis(self):
        self.h -= 1
        print("Hour left : " + str(self.h))


state = State()

d = "14:00"
sd.every(1).seconds.do(state.dothis)
state.dothis()
while True:
    sd.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Alternatively, if you want to leave your `dothis` function unchanged, you could make a more general class that takes a function and an initial value as arguments, and feeds the return value back into the function after every call:

```
import schedule as sd
import time


class CaptureReturn:
    def __init__(self, func, initial_state):
        self.func = func
        self.state = initial_state

    def call_func(self):
        self.state = self.func(self.state)


def dothis(h):
    h -= 1
    print("Hour left : " + str(h))
    return h


h = 24
capture_return = CaptureReturn(dothis, h)
sd.every(1).seconds.do(capture_return.call_func)
capture_return.call_func()
while True:
    sd.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

You can also modify the above example to use decorators for extra style points, e.g.:

```
import schedule as sd
import schedule as sd
import time


def capture_return(initial_state):
    state = initial_state

    def decorator(f):
        def _wrapped():
            nonlocal state
            state = f(state)
            return state

        return _wrapped

    return decorator


@capture_return(initial_state=24)
def dothis(h):
    h -= 1
    print("Hour left : " + str(h))
    return h


sd.every(1).seconds.do(dothis)
print('manually calling:', dothis())
while True:
    sd.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you Oli! I tried all 3 answers. All are great. As I had not yet used decorators, the 3rd answer was really helpful and educational.